# How can I prevent Powerpoint from dropping the anchor text in my links?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

Powerpoint 2010 loses the anchor portion of links to external web sites.

- Select an object or text
- Insert -> Hyperlink
- Address: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PowerPoint#Criticism
- ok
- Save
- Exit (from power point)
- Restart it
- Go back to the anchor object/text and right click on it
- Edit Hyperlink
- Note how the "#Criticism" part has vanished.

My version:

- Help->About reports: Version: 14.0.6112.5000 (32-bit)

Does anywone know a way to get around this?

Comment: The hackish, I-don't-know-anything-about-the-nature-of-your-problem solution: http://bit.ly/ .

Comment: Ok, so I answered my own question.  Go ahead and paste in the URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PowerPoint#Criticism, and replace the # with "%23" like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PowerPoint%23Criticism. When you save it, it'll get corrected to a # character and will work when you reopen it.

Comment: @digitxp -- doh, that's an excellent solution as well.

Comment: Go ahead and post it as an answer--upvoting is fun.

Comment: Yup, please use the **answer your question** button. That way, you can mark it as accepted later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I answered my own question.

- Go ahead and paste in the URL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PowerPoint#Criticism as mentioned in the question
- Replace the # with "%23" like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_PowerPoint%23Criticism

When you save it, it'll get corrected to a # character and will work when you reopen it.

Comment: But when you save it again, PPT once again trashes the link.  It's a bug that's now been reported to MS.  With any luck, maybe we'll see a SP that fixes it.

Comment: Is there a link to the bug?

Comment: Not that I know of ... I don't think MS exposes its internal bugtracking to us civilians.